# How to get the sheet object in the sheet properties?

Tags: javascript

How to get the form object?

I use this.box meaning sheet.box here, but the script produces an error. How do I get the sheet object in the sheet properties?

```
<div class="box">
    <form action=""></form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sheet={
        box: $('.box'),
        form: this.box.find('form') // TypeError: this.box is undefined
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No, you can't, because the rhs has to be evaluated first before it even does any assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is a function:

```
form: function() {return this.box.find('form');}
```

Otherwise, you should be more specific.

Comment: thank you ,it should be want I want

Answer (score 0):

Old versions of Firefox (I tried Firefox 4 which warns but still accepts it) actually allowed you to do this:

```
var sheet = {
    box: #1= $('.box'),
    form: #1#.find('form')
}
```